# What happens if the AWS Key for S3 encryption is lost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have a S3 bucket that I created using cloudformation.

```
RenditionsBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketEncryption:
      ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
            KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref BucketEncryptionKey
    CorsConfiguration:
      CorsRules:
        - AllowedHeaders:
            - "*"
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - POST
            - PUT
            - DELETE
          AllowedOrigins:
            - "*"
```

I set its default encryption to `ServerSideEncryptionByDefault`. The SSE Algorithm is `aws:kms`.

I also generate a key as follows

```
BucketEncryptionKey:
  Type: AWS::KMS::Key
  Properties:
    Enabled: true
    KeyPolicy:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: kms:*
          Principal:
            AWS: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
          Resource: "*"
```

Now, this encrypts the documents at rest on the sever. However, what happens if my `BucketEncryptionKey` key is lost? Is it possible to lose this key or get in a state where its impossible to decrypt the data?

Answer (score 4):

The objects in S3 are encrypted under your AWS KMS Customer Master Key (CMK),
so that CMK *must* be usable in order to decrypt each object.

Because of this, if you delete a CMK, the data is unrecoverable.

This can actually be a great benefit if you want to delete
a large quantity of data in a distributed system.
Deleting (and sometimes even just finding) a lot of things is hard.
Verifying that you deleted all of those things and that they are unrecoverable is even harder.
Deleting one thing (the CMK in this case) is much easier,
and will result in all data that was encrypted under that key becoming unrecoverable.

This characteristic of encrypted data is one reason why you cannot directly delete CMKs.
You can *schedule* a CMK deletion[1] a minimum of seven days in the future (default is 30).
The CMK is disabled when you schedule deletion,
but it is not deleted until the deletion date.

If you realize that you need a CMK between scheduling the deletion and the deletion date,
you can cancel the deletion.

Similarly, if you created the CMK through CloudFormation,
then when CloudFormation "deletes" the CMK resource,
what it actually does is schedule the CMK deletion.
By default, this is scheduled 30 days in the future,
but if you set a "PendingWindowInDays" value[2],
you can select a custom period between 7 and 30 days.

For more information about this, see the CMK deletion documentation[3].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduleKeyDeletion.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html#aws-resource-kms-key-properties

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/deleting-keys.html

Answer (score 3):

`AWS::KMS::Key` is a customer master key, and there isn't technically anything stopping you from deleting one, which is presumably the most likely way for one to be "lost."  Hence this warning:

> Deleting a customer master key (CMK) in AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) is destructive and potentially dangerous. It deletes the key material and all metadata associated with the CMK and is irreversible. After a CMK is deleted, you can no longer decrypt the data that was encrypted under that CMK, which means that data becomes unrecoverable.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/deleting-keys.html

Theoretically, a serious malfunction, defect, sabotage, or catastrophic event impacting Key Management Service (KMS) could also result in the loss of a key, but these appear to be less likely than human error by the account owner.  Encrypting data at rest is risky business, by its nature -- the encrypted data is *intentionally* unusable without the key.

S3 doesn't actually encrypt the stored data with the master key, directly.  Instead, it uses separate encryption keys and the keys are encrypted using the master key... but without the master key, those data keys can't be decrypted, either.  S3 does not store the keys in plaintext, and doesn't even retain the plaintext version of the keys in memory any longer than necessary for encrypting or decrypting objecta in flight.

> S3 [...] removes the plaintext key from memory as soon as possible after use.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-s3.html

Comment: Do you know the common vulnerabilities when using KMS? As in "losing" the key.

Answer (score 0):

If your CMK was built using imported key material, then you have a raw copy of the data key. Try downloading the object without encryption and specify your raw material.

Logic states this should work, but AWS might prevent it for some reason.
I'll give it a shot and see if I can make it work.